# Why some sites are not shown when embedding them in an iframe?

Tags: xss, dvwa

Exploiting the [DVWA's](http://www.dvwa.co.uk/) stored XSS option, I'm using the following payload: `<iframe src="url">`.

I'd like to know why do some sites work but others don't when using this payload.

For example: `<iframe src="http://usatoday.com">`works, however `<iframe src="http://google.com">`does not work (it shows an empty box). This site doesn't work either.

Comment: There are many ways to protect you from being framed. I doubt that google uses only one of them.... https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be controlled with the following HTTP header:

```
Header set X-Frame-Options
```

It has the following options:

- DENY: Stops all framing
- SAMEORIGIN: Stops framing except for the same website that delivered
  the page itself. (Allowing http://www.example.com/ to frame pages
  served from http://www.example.com/ with X-Frame-Options set to this
  value)

If we look at google:

```
root@bt:~# telnet google.com 80
Trying 173.194.34.192...
Connected to google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.google.es/
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=33213a21c9470cd8:FF=0:TM=1372280788:LM=1372280788:S=uhe-vKiypMTkoLNP; expires=Fri, 26-Jun-2015 21:06:28 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
Set-Cookie: NID=67=pl37RO9ptszDuKjsU8ysb4W3bkos7KK0u28rPbWdM-hJsNo_gS_XFd1dtWSHM7zAeDjITumqHWIw6P836EqfGSZk51m7nioFM6SrQHZzVVEHgDjXL1CpTmGRrdjP4d_L; expires=Thu, 26-Dec-2013 21:06:28 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
Date: Wed, 26 Jun 2013 21:06:28 GMT
Server: gws
Content-Length: 218
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN   <----

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.es/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

We can see that they have set the X-Frame-Options have been set to SAMEORIGIN. This is preventing you from iFraming the website.

Comment: Yup, correct. Here you can find some more examples and explanation: https://steemit.com/security/@gaottantacinque/steemit-security-check-iframe-tricks

Answer (score 10):

Websites commonly use iframe breakers written in JavaScript or the [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header) header to prevent being iframed.

In the case of google.com, the latter is the case:

```
fabian ~% curl -I www.google.com | grep Frame
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```